# XML viewer with Tcl/Tk

Tags: xml, tree, tcl

Is there any XML tree viewer implemented in Tcl/Tk (preferably 8.4)? I'm looking for something similar to http://xmlgrid.net/ - a tool that reads XMl, displays it as a tree and allows me to get XPath for each node. I don't need editing capabilities, just viewing.
Thanks, Yoram

Answer (score 1):

The [starDOM](http://wiki.tcl.tk/12550) viewer/editor is a good place to start (the source code is in that wiki page). It requires the [tDOM](http://tdom.github.com/) package as its DOM implementation (I'd recommend that anyway; tDOM's a really nice DOM implementation).